# Continuous from the left/right

Tags: piecewise-continuity

Here's a related problem from:
[Piecewise Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2164159/piecewise-function)

$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
 4^x&\text{if}\, x\leq 1\\
 \frac{9-x^2}{3-x}&\text{if}\, 1<x\leq 4\\
      \sqrt x&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

(b) at which of these numbers is f continuous from the right, the left, or neither?

I want to know what intervals I should take when discussing the continuity from the left of $x=4$.
Should it be $(-\infty, 4)$ or $(1,4)$?
As the first interval would yield a discontinuity unlike in the second interval.

Comment: If you're talking about the continuity at a point, it shouldn't depend on any particular interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: you can just look at $(1,4)$.

More formally, recall from the definition of continuity that $f$ will be continuous at $x=4$ if:

- $f(4)$ exists;
- the limit $L = \lim_{x\to 4}f(x)$ exists; and
- $f(4) = L$

The limit here doesn't care whether there are other discontinuities; the behaviour at $x=1$ is irrelevant. You are free to choose as small an interval around $x=4$ as you like, so for simplicity it is fine to assume that $x>1$.